# Kubernetes Dashboard doesn't see my master node

Tags: kubernetes

I have one master node, and it looks like everything ok.

[image]

But I open the dashboard and I see many errors.

[image]

Comment: is this aks? what is the version?

Comment: no ,my master version v1.18.2

Answer (score 1):

The system:anonymous is not authorized to perform the list actions within your cluster.

You can solve this case in 2 ways:

1 - Using RBAC Authorization, described in [k8s documentation here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/access-authn-authz/rbac/).

2 - A **NOT recommended** way is explained in this [GitHub thread](https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/apiserver-builder-alpha/issues/225):

```
kubectl create clusterrolebinding cluster-system-anonymous --clusterrole=dont-do-this --user=system:anonymous
```

At the end of the GitHub thread, the Kubernetes team explains why this is not a recommended approach:

> [...] granting anonymous clients full access to the Kubernetes API [...] should not be considered as solutions to permission issues

But if you are not in Production and would like to check if it works first, that can help.
You can double check and create the proper Cluster Role and Cluster Role Binding afterwards.